# __fspath__() function in PathLike object

Tags: python, parsing, path, filesystems

I'm trying to implement a PathLike object and use fspath command to retrieve the o/p from **fspath** function.

What I'm expecting is, if a PathLike object is passed to fspath function, it should return the value of **fspath** (here it should return the path in bytes). However, it is still returning in str.

```
import os,pathlib
class imp(os.PathLike):
 def __init__(self,path):
  self.path=path
 def __fspath__(path):
  return bytes(path)
re=imp('/etc/')
print(os.fspath(re.path))

Output: '/etc/'

Expected output : b '/etc/'
```

Can you please let me know where I went wrong and how should I change the code so that it works as expected?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you’re calling `fspath` on `re.path` instead of on `re`.

While `re` is a pathlike object, for which `fspath` will use the `__fspath__` protocol, `re.path` is just a string, so it returns the string unchanged.

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike.__fspath__) say:

> If `str` or `bytes` is passed in, it is returned unchanged. Otherwise `__fspath__()` is called and its value is returned as long as it is a `str` or `bytes` object. In all other cases, `TypeError`is raised.

Meanwhile, your `__fspath__` is wrong in two ways. First it’s a method, which should take `self` and do something with `self.path`; as-is, you’re taking that `self` as a variable named `path` and trying to use it as a string. Second, you have to call `encode` on your string (with the appropriate encoding—which is usually the fs encoding, although in that case you don’t even need to bother and can just return a string), not pass it to the `bytes` constructor.

Also, for debugging purposes, it would had been a lot easier to spot the problem if your string and bytes were completely unrelated. If, say, `re.path` were `'unicodepath'` while `__fspath__` returned `’8bitpath'`, it would be pretty clear whether it was ignoring your method or deciding things behind your back.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

`__fspath__` should be defined as

```
def __fspath__(self):
    return self.path.encode('utf8')
```

Then used as

```
os.fpath(re)
```

When `re` is the argument to `fspath`, the method `re.__fspath__` will be automatically invoked, and it should return the value of `re.path`--not directly, but properly encoded as a `bytes` object.